# Getting undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass on the view new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and i'm learning, so i was following this tutorial 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
but when i try to add the error message i get undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
at this piece of code:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
     <%= form_for :posts, url: posts_path do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %> // <-- **HERE**
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>
              <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
```

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
      @posts = Post.new(posts_params)
    if @posts.save
        redirect_to @posts
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:title, :description)
  end  
end
```

This is my view that is giving me an error in full:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for :posts, url: posts_path do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this post from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

My model: 



 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

        validates :title, 
                :presence => {:message => "Title can't be blank." },
                :uniqueness => {:message => "Title already exists."},
                 length: { minimum: 5 }

        validates :description, 
        :presence =>{:message => "Description can't be blank." }
    end
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have the following:

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
```

but in your controller, you have:

```
 def new
    @posts = Post.new
  end

 def create
    @posts = Post.new(posts_params)
    ...
 end
```

Rename `@posts` to `@post` in your controller.

So, the code has to look like this:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

 def create
    @post = Post.new(posts_params)
    ...
 end
```

Comment: i have this now

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @post = Post.all
  end

  def new
   @post = Post.all
  end

  def create
     @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
 else
  render 'new'
 end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end

and im getting undefined method `errors' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Just changed the @posts to @post as u said

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it first. Change Post.all to Post.new

Comment: Oh man thank you so much, that totally worked i tried that before actually but only changed one of them, now everything is working fine :D

Comment: Got another problem :T


Index view:


<h1>Listing posts</h1>
 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
 
  <% @posts.each do |posts| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= posts.title %></td>
      <td><%= posts.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', posts_path(posts) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_posts_path(posts) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

Getting this error undefined method `each' for #<Post:0xa93ef2c>

Comment: At @posts.each do |posts|

Comment: Index should have `posts` and not `post`

Comment: But their all '@posts', am i missing something ? eveything on controller is '@posts' now

Comment: 'def index
   @posts = Post.new
  end'

Comment: '<h1>This is the index page</h1>
<p>I need to get the new action running!</p>
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts' %>
</br>
<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>

<h1>Listing posts</h1>
 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
 
  <% @posts.each do |posts| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= posts.title %></td>
      <td><%= posts.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', posts_path(posts) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_posts_path(posts) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>'

Comment: please help? im not being ablt to find the cause

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest, just one thing :-

- Since you are new to ruby please just try the convetional way to get the validation errors and displaying it as per the validations first, then you can go on experimenting the cause and other ways to get to the root cause.

you can try like :-

```
In controller

def new
 @post = Post.new
end
```

and In your View

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
 ---you code here --
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`new` action can be used to validate the params just before saving into the database hence calling `some_obj = obj.new(params)` and then `som_obj.errors` would definetly have the errors listed if valid params are not provided

Answer (score 0):

The error is that **you've not declared `@post`**

--

You need to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @post = Post.new
   end
end

#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
   <% if @post.errors.any? %>
      ...
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will set the correct `@post` variable, which should give you the ability to call the `.errors` method on it.

---

As a sidenote,

> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

This error is often confused with new developers.

They think that their problem is `errors` method is missing; the *real* issue is that **your variable is undeclared**

Since [Ruby is object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), it treats each variable as an *object*. Unlike other languages - which would raise exception based on the variable being undeclared, Ruby populates the `nil:NilClass` object.

Thus, whenever you see the above error, always remember that it means you've called a non-declared variable.